# How to override standard global function in c++ when called on a class just like in defining __str__ in python

Tags: c++, string

Main question:

In python, we can define things like `__unicode__` or `__str__` in a class, that way when we call `print()` or `str()` on a class (i.e. `str(myclass)`), we get a customized and readable string representation.  In C++, how can this be done for a class? Such that when we call `string(myclass)` we get a string representation of `myclass`?

Backstory:

This will probably be tagged as a low quality question, as I am very new to C++.

I'm currently working through the C++ exercises in exercism.io, where the point is to write code to enable the provided test cases to pass. I have already finished 30 of the 39 available exercises, however I am currently stuck on this particular test case code:

```
const auto actual = string(date_independent::clock::at(t.hour, t.minute));
```

In the previous exercises, I understood this as "create a namespace named `date_independent`, have a class in it with the name `clock`, and make the class have a public function named `at`, that will accept two parameters(in this case 2 integers hour and minute)". I made the function a `static` function because the test code does not really instantiate a clock object. I also made the return value to be of type `std::string`. It worked well for the first few test cases.  Unfortunately, I then encountered this test code:

```
const auto actual = string(date_independent::clock::at(a.hour, a.minute).plus(a.add));
```

In this instance, my previous solution of returning a string backfired since now I need to call a `plus()` function on the return value of `at()`.  This obviously cannot be done since `at()` returns a `std::string`, and strings don't have member functions. This was then I noticed that there's a `string()` function (?) encapsulating the entire `date_independent::clock::at(a.hour, a.minute).plus(a.add)`.  I'm not sure however where this `string()` function is coming from, and how I could find out.  For python, I would assume that this is some sort of type casting into string, or some other function named string. However, this is C++, and I haven't encountered typecasting done like this yet, so maybe it isn't that.  My other idea is that, similar to python, maybe classes can override how standard global functions work with them.  Like say when `__unicode__` or `__str__` is defined in a python class so that print statements can return customized values.

So my question once again is, is my assumption that this `string` function is supposed to be a member function that is meant to be overridden correct? And if it is, how can it be done in C++? I would appreciate any responses.  I'm fairly certain that I'm not seeing something fundamental, since I'm new to the language.

Some of the context of the test code is found below.

```
...

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(time_tests)
{
    for (timeTest t : timeCases) {
        const auto actual = string(date_independent::clock::at(t.hour, t.minute));

        BOOST_REQUIRE_MESSAGE(t.expected == actual, errorMsg(t.expected, actual, t.msg));
    }
}

...

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(add_tests)
{
    for (addTest a : addCases) {
        const auto actual = string(date_independent::clock::at(a.hour, a.minute).plus(a.add));

        BOOST_REQUIRE_MESSAGE(a.expected == actual, errorMsg(a.expected, actual, a.msg));
    }
}

...
```

Comment: `string(x)` most likely isn’t a `string()` function but a constructor call of `std::string`. You’d allow conversion to `std::string` by having a suitable conversion operator, in this case a class member `operator std::string()`.

Comment: Yes, I also think that `string(x)` is actually from `std::string`, since the code has `using namespace std`. I googled your suggested keyword `conversion operator` and got these couple of pages: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr383.htm http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator . Are these what you mean?

Comment: But regardless, it looks promising.  I'll try it out.

Comment: Yes, you literally add `operator std::string() const { /* implementation goes here */ }` to your class.

Comment: @DietmarKühl This works as expected, thanks! If you still want, you can put this in an answer so that I can choose it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If want to output your class in console or write it to a file, you have to override the `<<` operator for your class.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const person& person)
{
    return os << person.first_name << " " << person.last_name;
}
```

If you just want a `std::string`, just add a `to_string` method that returns the string reprentation of your class.

```
class person
{
public:

    std::string to_string() const
    {
        return first_name + " " + last_name;
    }

private:

    std::string first_name;
    std::string last_name;
};
```

Comment: Hi, I am not really trying to output the string onto the console or file.  I am however trying to get this code to return a string: `const auto actual = string(date_independent::clock::at(a.hour, a.minute).plus(a.add));`.  The variable `actual` should be of type `std::string`. I'm assuming that the function `string` is responsible for "stringifying" whatever result `date_independent::clock::at(a.hour, a.minute).plus(a.add)`, however, I am not sure how this `string`function works, or if it's something that needs to be defined for the `clock` class.

Comment: It seems the test cases are given: how does your approach help to satisfy the test cases which effectively use `string(x)`?

Comment: There is nothing like this in C++. You have to write your own method to convert the values in your class to a string.